Properties of fourier series on $SO(3)$
With standard fourier series we can use some identities like convolution theorem and Parseval's theorem:

(convolution theorem) Fourier series of the convolution of $f$ and $g$ is the point-wise product of fourier series of $f$ and $g$, and
(Parseval's theorem) The $L^2$ norms of $f$ and its convolution are the same.

But now I need equivalent theorems for functions with domain $SO(3)$ (where standard fourier series are used on functions with domain $SO(2)$). I have only yet found the definition of "Fourier series" for these functions, here. The equivalent statement of convolution theorem translates simply, but for Parseval's theorem we also need the definition of $L^2$ norm of the Fourier series. Do these equivalents still hold in this case? These theories are far ahead of my knowledge and I can't get deep into them now, I would really appreciate some quick explanations and answers that I can somewhat understand.

Disclaimer: I apologize in advance for this answer. I tried motivating the abstract theory but now after I'm done I fear I missed the point. However, now that I produced this not-so-small amount of text I thought I post it anyways as it may help you finding what you are looking for (by providing some terminology).
Classical Fourier theory is done on $\mathbb R$ (classical Fourier transform) or the circle $\mathbb S_1 \cong SO(2)$ (Fourier series of periodic signals). In fact, both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb S_1$ are just examples of locally compact abelian (LCA) groups for which there is a well-developed Fourier theory. In fact, for a LCA group, we may define the dual group $\widehat G = \{\alpha\colon G\to\mathbb S_1\text{ continuous group homomorphism}\}$. The elements $\alpha\in\widehat G$ are called characters and we may define a Fourier transform of $f\in L^1(G)$ via
$$
\hat f \colon\widehat G \to\mathbb C,\quad \hat f(\alpha) = \int_G f(x)\overline{\alpha(x)}\ dx.
$$
Here, $dx$ denotes the Haar measure on $G$, which you can think of as the uniform distribution of mass on $G$. In our two special cases above we get:

$\widehat{\mathbb R}$ consist of the group homomorphisms $e_\xi\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb S_1, x\mapsto e^{i\xi x}$ with $\xi \in \mathbb R$ so we can identify $\mathbb R$ and $\widehat{\mathbb R}$ via $\xi\mapsto e_\xi$. The Haar measure $dx$ on $\mathbb R$ is just the Lebesgue measure and we thus obtain
$$
\hat f(\xi) = \hat f(e_\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-i\xi x}\ dx.
$$

On the other hand $\widehat{\mathbb S_1}$ consists of the group homomorphisms $\alpha_n\colon \mathbb S_1\to\mathbb S_1, z\mapsto z^n$. We may thus identify $\mathbb Z=\widehat{\mathbb S_1}$ via $n\mapsto \alpha_n$. The Haar measure $dz$ on $\mathbb S_1$ is just $\frac{1}{2\pi}\ d\theta$ if we parametrize $z=e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb S_1$ by its angle $\theta$. Thus
$$
\hat f(n) = \hat f(\alpha_n) = \int_{\mathbb S_1} f(z) z^{-n}\ dz = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) e^{-in\theta}\ d\theta. 
$$


Thus we reobtain our classical theory and in fact all the neat results we know for Fourier theory on $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb S_1$ just carry over in this setting. Since $\widehat G$ is again a LCA group with a Haar measure we get the following Plancherel theorem: For $f\in L^1(G)\cap L^2(G)$ we have
$$
\int_G |f(x)|^2 dx = \int_{\widehat G} |\hat f(\alpha)|^2 d\alpha
$$
and this extends to an isometric isomorphism $L^2(G)\to L^2(\widehat G)$.
Note that $\widehat{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R$ also carries the Lebesgue measure as its Haar measure, while $\widehat{\mathbb S_1} = \mathbb Z$ has the counting measure as its Haar measure (these are the most natural uniform distributions respecting the group structure) and we obtain

For $G=\mathbb R$ we get (by normalizing the Lebesgue measure suitably)
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2\ dx = \int_{\mathbb R} |\hat f(x)|^2\ dx.
$$

For $G=\mathbb S_1$ we get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(e^{i\theta})|^2\ d\theta = \int_{\mathbb Z} |\hat f(n)|^2\ dn = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat f(n)|^2.
$$


So far for the LCA case. Big Problem: $SO(3)$ is not abelian so sadly we can't apply the theory above.
A big problem is, that if $G$ is not abelian, there is no use in defining the dual group $\widehat G$, as often there are no or only few non-trivial group homomorphisms $G\to\mathbb S_1$ (since $\mathbb S_1$ is abelian).
We hence need to find a suitable generalization of $\widehat G$ which we can study and use to formulate an analogon of the Plancherel theorem.
As it turns out the suitable object to look at is
$$
\widehat G = \left. \{\text{unitary irreducible representations of G}\} \middle/ \text{equivalence}\right.
$$
There is also a natural topology on $\widehat G$, the hull-kernel topology/Fell topology. Abstract theory tells us that for a large class of locally compact groups (so-called postliminaire/type-I groups) there exists a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\widehat G$ such that we can formulate a Plancherel theorem for some "Fourier transform".
Since $\widehat G$ (in opposition to the LCA case) is not a group anymore, this measure will in general not be a "uniform distribution" (after all, how should we measure "uniformity" without any structure that gives us a notion of motion like translation on $\mathbb R$ or more generally any group $G$) and the measure may very well look like a discrete measure in some places of $\widehat G$ and like some continuous measure (like Lebesgue) in other places. This theory is quite involved and there seems to be no hope in understanding these "Plancherel measures" for arbitrary type-I groups.
But there is a silver lining. While $SO(3)$ is not abelian, it is a compact group. Thus it is in some sense "small" and we are actually able to understand it.
In fact, Fourier theory for compact topological groups $G$ is understood via the Peter-Weyl theorem. It tells us that every unitary representation of a compact group decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible unitary finite-dimensional representations, so these are the building blocks of all unitary representations. It also tells us that $\widehat G$ is discrete and that we can define a Fourier transform for $f\in L^1(G)$ via
$$
\hat f(\pi) = \int_G f(x) \pi(x)\ dx,
$$
where $\pi\colon G\to U(H_\pi)$ is a unitary irreducible finite-dimensional representation of $G$ on a Hilbert space $H_\pi$. In fact, the Peter-Weyl theorem states that we get an isometric isomorphism
$$
\mathcal{F}\colon\ L^2(G) \cong \widehat\bigoplus_{\pi\in\widehat G} End(H_\pi) = \int_{\widehat G}^\oplus End(H_\pi)\ d\mu(\pi) =: L^2(\widehat G)
$$
mapping some $f\in L^2(G)\subseteq L^1(G)$ to its Fourier transform
$$
f \mapsto \hat f = (\hat f(\pi))_{\pi\in\widehat G} = \sum_{\pi\in\widehat G} \hat f(\pi).
$$
Here we give each $H_\pi$ the inner product $\langle A, B\rangle_\pi = \dim(H_\pi) \text{ tr}(AB^*)$, so that
$$
\|f\|_{L^2(G)}^2 = \|\hat f\|_{L^2(\widehat G)}^2 = \sum_{\pi\in\widehat G} \dim(H_\pi) \text{ tr}\big(\hat f(\pi)\hat f(\pi)^*\big).
$$
This is the Plancherel theorem for compact groups.
There is also a Fourier inversion theorem stating
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)(x) = \sum_{\pi\in\widehat G} \dim(\pi) \text{ tr}(g(\pi)\pi(x^{-1})) = \sum_{\pi\in\widehat G} \langle g(\pi), \pi(x)\rangle_\pi
$$
so that
$$
f(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat f)(x) = \sum_{\pi\in\widehat G}\dim(\pi) \text{ tr}(\hat f(\pi)\pi(x^{-1})) = \sum_{\pi\in\widehat G} \langle\hat f(\pi), \pi(x)\rangle_\pi.
$$
If $G$ were compact and abelian, we could identify this situation with the LCA situation. In fact, all $H_\pi$ would be one dimensional, so that we can identify $End(H_\pi) \cong \mathbb C$ and we could identify the unitary dual $\widehat G$ with the dual group $\widehat G$, so there would be no conflicting notation. For example for $G=\mathbb S_1$ we could identify $\widehat\bigoplus_{\pi\in\widehat{\mathbb S_1}} End(H_\pi) \cong {\mathbb C}^{\mathbb Z}$, so we could indeed identify $\hat f$ with a function $\hat f\colon\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$, the Fourier series coefficients.
Even nicer: $SO(3)$ is not only a compact group, it is a compact Lie group, thus we have the full arsenal of structure theory at our hands and we can actually make efforts to classify $\widehat{SO(3)}$. Since $SO(3)$ is second countable, we finde that $\widehat{SO(3)}$ is countable, so our direct sums above will just become sums over $\mathbb Z$ and the Weyl dimension formula will allow us to compute the dimensions $\dim(\pi)$.
The dual $\widehat{SO(3)}$ is computed quite hands on for example in the book by Faraut, where you can also find the Peter-Weyl theorem (see 6.4.1 and 6.4.2). There is also the book by Deitmar and Echterhoff, which is written a bit more abstractly but also yields a sneak peek at the general Plancherel theorem. For a complete treatise on the general theory I guess the standard reference still remains the book by Dixmier. One could ask for which type-I groups except the LCA and compact groups we have detailed information on the Plancherel measure. Two big classes we understand are the nilpotent Lie groups (Dixmier, Kirillov, ...) and semi-simple Lie groups (Harish-Chandra), see for example the book by Warner.
Faraut, Jacques, Analysis on Lie groups. An introduction, Mathématiques en Devenir 101. Paris: Calvage et Mounet (ISBN 2-916352-00-7/pbk). xi, 313 p. (2006). ZBL1096.22001.
Deitmar, Anton; Echterhoff, Siegfried, Principles of harmonic analysis, Universitext. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-05791-0/hbk; 978-3-319-05792-7/ebook). xiii, 332 p. (2014). ZBL1300.43001.
Dixmier, Jacques, [C^*-Algebras] North-Holland (ISBN 0444863915) 1982
Warner, Garth, [Harmonic Analysis on Semi-Simple Lie Groups I/II], Springer (ISBN 364250275X) 1972

This is an amazing answer! Thank you very much for all the effort you put into it. It helped me a lot in guidance.
